# Is it possible to do SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... OR ... IN( Checking for 2 conditions in a subquery)?

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to check if any of the 2 columns of my table match with result of the subquery. Currently, I'm doing SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (var1 IN SUBQUERY OR var2 IN SUBQUERY) and it works. But those 2 subqueries are the same, so I think performance could be improved if I could check for if any of the var1 or var2 is in the SUBQUERY. Could this be done without doing the subquery twice?

I've tried something like SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE var1 OR var2 IN SUBQUERY, but this of course doesn't work, because WHERE sees it as 2 different conditions like(var1) OR (var2 IN SUBQUERY).
The query that currently works that I want to increase performance of is the below:

```
SELECT table1.id FROM table1 WHERE (table1.first IN (SELECT table2.id FROM table2 WHERE (table2.xCord BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (table2.yCord BETWEEN ? AND ?)) OR table1.second IN (SELECT table2.id FROM table2 WHERE (table2.xCord BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (table2.yCord BETWEEN ? AND ?)))
```

So subquery is this:

```
SELECT table2.id FROM table2 WHERE (table2.xCord BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (table2.yCord BETWEEN ? AND ?)
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the subquery?

Comment: Showing the piece of code and query you have tried will go a long way towards having your question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest your subquery inside a `WITH` clause and use a CTE like this:

```
with cte as (
  SELECT id FROM table2 
  WHERE (xCord BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (yCord BETWEEN ? AND ?)
)
SELECT id FROM table1 
WHERE (first IN cte) OR (second IN cte)
```

Comment: Does this mean that subquery is run only once?

Comment: Yes it executes only once.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, but maybe you are better of with a common table expression and left joins anyway.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

```
with subquery as (select col ....)
select table.* from table
    left join subquery s1 on table.var1 = s1.col
    left join subquery s2 on table.var2 = s2.col
where not (s1.col is null and s2.col is null)
```

This executes the query only once, the left join contains all rows from table. If there is no row from the subquery to join on var1, s1.col is null. Similar for s2. So if both are null you don't include the row in the final result. Depending on your data, you may need to `select distinct`